# How do hero prices change over time in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I saw Vikings were introduced with 15 kGold price, now they are 10 kGold. Can one expect further decrease in the price or it happens only when a hero is new?

What is the tendency for hero prices changes over time?
*(Note, I'm Not asking for rumours like "what is Blizzard going to do?", I am asking for facts on other heroes prices changes).*

Comment: Prices tend to go down over time, but it is entirely at the discretion of Blizzard. I think most heroes will eventually settle at the 5k mark.

Comment: @TZHX, so I can expect Vikings be cheaper. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule is when a new hero is introduced, he/she/it is 15k gold and then it will drop to 10k gold in 2-3 weeks time. Other price changes depend on Blizzard and do not follow any particular pattern like new heroes (Since November, only Stitches went from 10k to 7k).